# Rotate a list to the left in Scheme/Racket

Tags: list, scheme, racket

Trying to rotate a list left in scheme/racket.
For example: (rotate-left '(abc)) outputs (bca)

Here's ze code!

```
(define (rotate-left LIST)
    (if(null? LIST)'()
        (cons(car LIST)(cons(cdr LIST)'())))))
```

Unfortunately this just outputs the same list! Should be an easy fix I'm sure, and I know I'm close...Thanks for any help !

Comment: Will the input list never be nested?  If it can be nested, do you want the nesting entirely preserved in the output or should the output be flat?  If the input can be nested, should the first s-expression be rotated or the first atom?  Problems have to be well specified, particularly the assumptions that can be made about the input and the requirements of the output.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using list representation here?  This kind of problem seems well suited for a cyclic data structure, so that the rotation is implied by just walking through the structure.  More information please!  In what context do you need this operation?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You got car and cdr backwards !  Here you go :

```
(define (rotate-left LIST)
    (if(null? LIST)'()
        (cons(cdr LIST)(cons(car LIST)'())))))
```

Comment: I guess you need to flatten the resulting list as well - `(define (rotate-left LIST)
        (flatten (cons (cdr LIST) (car LIST))))`

Comment: @DonJohnson did you actually _test_ this answer? because it doesn't work, you know ... even after fixing the compilation problem, `(rotate-left '(a b c))` is returning `'((b c) a)`. Take a look at my answer for a working solution.

Comment: @Ankur good spot, although it assumes the function spec requires that the input list always be flat. If the input list is allowed to be nested, you should use append instead.

Answer (score 9):

The answer given by @davepmiller doesn't work ... Here's a correct implementation - you have to replace the first `cons` with an `append` for adding the first element at the *end* of the list.

```
(define (rotate-left LIST)
  (if (null? LIST)
      '()
      (append (cdr LIST)
              (cons (car LIST)
                    '()))))


(rotate-left '(a b c))
> '(b c a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Test cases! Test cases! A check-expect here would have helped you understand the problem, and others to understand what you were looking for.

I think I'm getting old.